# Diamond render is showing more dark shade

Tags: shaders

Diamond render is showing more dark shade...how to resolve that...clear diamond.

[image]

Blend File Link : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1N41CXLkvBCIcugLHua7w95Kd7YDjoRz2?usp=sharing

Comment: you have a fancy diamond shader, have you done it yourself ?
for the question increase Glossy and Transparent in max bounces

Answer (score 5):

in render settings, just increase the light path max bounces:

[image]